# NSNumberFormatter only formats up to 14 significant digits

Tags: ios, precision, nsnumberformatter

I saw some code trying to format lat long using the following NSNumberFormatter.

```
NSNumberFormatter * sut = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[sut setMaximumFractionDigits:20]; // also tried set to 15 or 16, not working too.
[sut setMaximumSignificantDigits:20];

NSLocale *enUSPOSIXLocale = [[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
[sut setLocale:enUSPOSIXLocale];

NSString *expected = @"1.299129258067496"; // 16 significants digits
NSString *actual = [sut stringFromNumber:@(1.299129258067496)];

[[actual should] equal:expected];// Failed to pass, the actual is @"1.2991292580675"
```

Although in this case, we may not need to use the NSNumberFormatter to get the correct result, I'm wondering why NSNumberFormatter only returns string of up to 14 significant digits.

Answer (score 1):

It only shows 14 decimal places because the double type rounds at 15 decimal places. This worked for me because you can set the number of decimal places shown.

`[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.20f", 1.299129258067496]`

Just make sure the number of decimal places does not exceed the number otherwise the program makes up numbers to fill the rest. Hope this helps.

Comment: What value should I set minimumSignificantDigits to? tried 1 or 20, it's still not working. In the case of 1, the stringFromNumber returns the same result as in the question, in case of 20, the result has padding zeros. I cannot set the minimumSignificantDigits to 16 since it will only handle the case of 16 significant digits while the actually number to format can have different length.

Comment: I appreciate your help.
But the double type rounds at 16 decimal places in my test and your code above will result in 1.29912925806749601776.

I actually use `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", @(1.29912925806749666666)]` in my code which gives 16 significant digits. The question here is to ask about the NSNumberFormatter's behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, I could not find a way to get the NSNumberFormatter to display the proper number of digits. I think the formatter only takes 15 decimal places even if it lets you set it to more. Weird stuff.